# Laravel SEO friendly URLs

Tags: php, laravel

I started learning laravel and couldn't figure out how to solve a problem.
For example if i want to create a route for products i can use a route like below.

```php
Route::get('/product/{slug}',[ProductController::class,'index']);
```

In this approach we would get something like this **localhost/product/macbook-pro**. However i want to create a url like **localhost/macbook-pro**. In my project, where I did this with plain PHP using the $route variable, I was creating a table called links in the database and saving the links in it. I was doing the table structure and PHP side control as follows.
url | type | type_id
-- | -- | --
macbook-pro | product | 1
msi-laptop | product | 2

```php
if ($query = DB::table('links')
    ->where('url', route(0))
    ->first()
    ) {
    $type_id = $query['type_id'];
    $route[0] = $query['type'];
}
```

How can i get the same approach in laravel ?

Comment: although your question needs little more explanation to answer but for now to insert url use helper `slug` see this : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-slug

Comment: I can create slug urls. My question is how to dynamically get product by its slug url without writing a prefix for product,category etc.

Comment: If you want automatically use slug then First implement route model binding better use `resource` controller see this : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise key with [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name)

```
Route::get('/{product:slug}',[ProductController::class,'index']);
```

With this, you need unique field `slug` in your product model.

Comment: Will using this many times cause performance issues ? Using for product, category, brand and so on.

Comment: Nope - you just specify key in model for searching. Set index to slug fields - and it will fast as search by id